# Add a disk on my virtual machine Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am doing the this tutorial https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt771177.aspx

The thing is I made my virtual machine and asign to the lun a 0. 
The problem is I don t quite understand what does it mean to asign 0 to lun, and how does it affect that the following scrip to fail.

```
disk=Get-Disk | where {$_.PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"}
$diskNumber=$disk.Number
Initialize-Disk -Number $diskNumber
New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter
Format-Volume -DriveLetter F
```

disk=Get-Disk : The term 'disk=Get-Disk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ disk=Get-Disk | where {$_.PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (disk=Get-Disk:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Initialize-Disk : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Number'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the
argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:3 char:25
+ Initialize-Disk -Number $diskNumber
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Initialize-Disk], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Initialize-Disk

New-Partition : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DiskNumber'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for
the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:4 char:27
+ New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLet ...
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Partition], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-Partition

Format-Volume : No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'F'.  Verify the value of the
property and retry.
At line:5 char:1
+ Format-Volume -DriveLetter F
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:Char) [Format-Volume], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DriveLetter,Format-Volume

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the variable correctly.

Your code...

```
disk=Get-Disk | where {$_.PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"}
```

Needs to have a $ in front to make "disk" a variable

```
$disk = Get-Disk | where {$_.PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"}
```